# Error in loading up Minecraft in Eclipse IDE [1.12.2]

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is my first time posting here, I literally just made an account for this question. That being said, bear with me if I'm formatting things wrong.

I'm trying to learn how to write a 1.12.2 minecraft mod following various online tutorials. I currently have the base all set up - no content in it, just it existing as a mod. I am all good up to loading the Minecraft Environment in the Eclipse IDE. Whenever I try to run it, I get hit with an error.

Here is the console output: https://pastebin.com/DuG0QMSx

'''

```
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: []
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Running with arguments: [--userProperties, {}, --assetsDir, C:/Users/William/.gradle/caches/minecraft/assets, --assetIndex, 1.12, --accessToken{REDACTED}, --version, 1.12.2, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker]
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 14.23.5.2768 for Minecraft 1.12.2 loading
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_242, running on Windows 7:amd64:6.1, installed at C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot\jre
[00:12:42] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Apache Maven library folder was not in the format expected. Using default libraries directory.
[00:12:42] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Full: C:\Users\William\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.maven\maven-artifact\3.5.3\7dc72b6d6d8a6dced3d294ed54c2cc3515ade9f4\maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar
[00:12:42] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Trimmed: c:/users/william/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact/3.5.3/
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Managed to load a deobfuscated Minecraft name- we are in a deobfuscated environment. Skipping runtime deobfuscation
[00:12:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Detected deobfuscated environment, loading log configs for colored console logs.
2020-02-11 00:12:43,373 main WARN Disabling terminal, you're running in an unsupported environment.
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [FML]: Ignoring missing certificate for coremod FMLCorePlugin (net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin), we are in deobf and it's a forge core plugin
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [FML]: Ignoring missing certificate for coremod FMLForgePlugin (net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin), we are in deobf and it's a forge core plugin
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [FML]: Searching C:\Minecraft Modding\AoM-Pre1\run\.\mods for mods
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:12:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:12:45] [main/ERROR] [FML]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing
[00:12:45] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:12:45] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[00:12:46] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
[00:12:46] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[00:12:46] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[00:12:46] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[00:12:47] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:3158) ~[Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:42) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:3158) ~[Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:42) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 12 more
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]: Caused by: net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager$ExitTrappedException
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager.checkPermission(FMLSecurityManager.java:49)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:761)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:108)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:973)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:138)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
[00:12:47] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

'''

It *seems* that there's an error with my code/Eclipse getting my System Time or something? I've been searching the internet for solutions to this problem, as well as reaching out to other modders, but to no success. A friend of mine who studies computer science recommended I post here, so worth a shot I guess.

Anyway, yeah. I don't know what other information I'm supposed to provide here other than the console output, but I'll answer all questions to the best of my ability (obviously, since I'm asking for help).